# Add emoji to gmail subject line from data factory to logic app

Tags: gmail, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to add emoji to the gmail subject line in azure data factory and email is sent using azure logic apps. I'm not sure if they emoji feature is supported using the decimal or hexadecimal values. For instance when the pipeline fails use bomb emoji.

```
<table>  
    <tr>
        <th>Unicode Character Name:
        <td>BOMB  
    <tr>
        <th>Hexadecimal:
        <td>&#x1F4A3;   
    <tr>
        <th>Decimal:
        <td>&#128163;
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, pasting the emoji directly while sending the mail did the trick.

Below is the complete flow of my logic app.

[image]

##### Steps in detail :

[image]

In the next step, I have used switch action for different statuses and added `send an email (v2)` step.

[image]

Similarly, you can add cases with emoji's for the other statuses too.

##### Results:

[image]